# Assign type to a variable and pass it to template

Tags: c++, templates

I have the following code

```
template <typename T>
auto CallMe(int param) -> void {
    ...
}

auto Test(int userInput) -> void {
    int paramToUse = SomeFunction(userInput);
    if (userInput == 0) {
        CallMe<__int32>(paramToUse);
    } else if (userInput == 1) {
        CallMe<__int16>(paramToUse);
    } else if (userInput == 2) {
        CallMe<__int8>(paramToUse);
    } else if (userInput == 3) {
    ...
}
```

My question is, since all the calls to `CallMe()` is exactly the same except the template type `T`, is there a way in C++ to assign the type to a variable in each conditional branch, and pass it to `CallMe()` in one place, like

```
    typename T;

    if (userInput == 0) {
        T = __int32;
    } else if (userInput == 1) {
        T = __int16;
    } else if (userInput == 2) {
        T = __int8;
    } else if (userInput == 3) {
    ...

    CallMe<T>(paramToUse);
```

This way if the signature of `CallMe` is changed, only one line is needed to update.

Comment: What's the purpose of the trailing return type in `auto CallMe(int param) -> void`?

Comment: No purpose. Just my coding style. I prefer to specify all types so I don't have to guess when reading.

Comment: Wouldn't `void CallMe(int param)` do the same?

Comment: It is the same, but I prefer the new trailing return style. This way when having multiple function declarations in header file, all function names start at the same column.

Comment: __int32 looks weird

Comment: Just an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
decltype(CallMe<__int32>)* callable; // function pointer 

// set the function address as necessary 
if (userInput == 0) {
  callable = CallMe<__int32>;
} else if (userInput == 1) {
  callable = CallMe<__int16>;
} else if (userInput == 2) {
  callable = CallMe<__int8>;
} else {
 // ...
} 

callable(paramToUse); // call it
```

Comment: ? Your code is exactly my first code. And those conditions are just for demonstration.

Comment: @CrendKing I didn't notice that. See the updated version

Comment: Is there any significance of the `__int32` at the first line, or is it just a required placeholder?

Comment: @CrendKing just a placeholder. Any type would do.

Answer (score 2):

Runtime-conditional type aliases aren't possible, as C++ is a statically typed language; meaning all types have to be resolved at compile-time.

Depending on your scenario, you might find a solution using [std::variant](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant), however you'll have to pass either pass a new variable to your `CallMe` function, or replace the type of `paramToUse` with the variant.

Edit:

```
using VariantType = std::variant<std::monostate, std::uint8_t, std::uint16_t, std::uint32_t>;
void CallMe(const VariantType value) {
    if (const auto uint8Value = std::get_if<std::uint8_t>(&value))
        // use uint8Value in a meaningful way
    else if (const auto uint16Value = std::get_if<std::uint16_t>(&value))
        // ...
    
    // ...
}

void function(const int userInput) {
    const auto result = SomeFunction(userInput);
    
    VariantType value {};
    if (result == 0)
        value = static_cast<std::uint32_t>(123);
    else if (result == 1)
        value = static_cast<std::uint16_t>(1234);
    // more conditions
    CallMe(value);
}
```

Comment: Can you provide an example? Are you suggesting to change `CallMe` to be a regular, non-template function, and take a std::variant parameter?

Comment: Added, hope it helps!

Comment: I see. Basically you are replacing template with std::variant variable. Clever. Unfortunately, the real `CallMe` needs that `T` as template to do some `if constexpr` tricks.

Comment: Can you explain why exactly you need the type? As an example, if it's for an underlying function call (e.g. a call to external code), it can be avoided.

Comment: Note that all `CallMe<T>` are of same type, which means mapping between runtime `userInput` and compile-time `CallMe<T>` is possible. Though, your answer is certainly a nice solution to OPs original problem

Comment: Yeah, I learned `std::variant` today. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> since all the calls to `CallMe()` is exactly the same except the template type `T`, is there a way in C++ to assign the type to a variable in each conditional branch, and pass it to `CallMe()` in one place

There isn't, as far I know.

Well... there is `using`

```
if (userInput == 0) {
    using T = __int32;
} else if (userInput == 1) {
    using T = __int16;
} ...

CallMe<T>(paramToUse); // T is out of scope
```

but the scope of `using` doesn't extend to the call of the function.

The bad part of your example is that the type is decided from a run-time known value (`userInput`) so I don't see solution better than the one you're using.

Different if you can pass `userInput` as compile-time known value: in that case you can create a sort of type array (using `std::tuple`, for example) and select the type in the call.

For example, suppose `userInput` is a template parameter value (so known at compile-time) and the `userInput` value are sequenced starting from zero (as in your question), you can write

```
template <std::size_t userInput>
void Test ()
 {
   using typeArray = std::tuple<__int32, __int16, __int8>;

   CallMe<std::tuple_element_t<userInput, typeArray>>(paramToUse);
 }
```

Comment: Thanks. I noticed `using` has scope problem, that's why I created this question. I'm aware of integer template parameter usage. The [Vector class library](https://github.com/vectorclass) has lots of it. Your example turns `Test` into template function, which I can't do.

Comment: @CrendKing - "Test into template function, which I can't do" - So I think that the only way is the if-then-else-if (or also switch/case) solution.